# Load an empty string as a JSON in Python3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I can not use an empty string in `json.loads()`.

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  5 2018, 02:13:53) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is there a way to prevent the `JSDONDecodeError` and just return a default value (e.g. empty `dict`, `list` or `None`)? if `json.loads()` handle an empty string?

The background of my question is I read file contents and parse them with `json.loads`. But sometimes the files are empty (`size=0`). This is ok and not an error.
But I don't want to check the file size or content size before using `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use coalescing to pass it something valid.

```
json.loads('' or 'null')
```

Comment: I tried to find an official python document explaining that concept. But couldn't find one. Can you give a hint?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: This is a technical reference and not an explanation of the "coalescing" concept.

Comment: "The expression `x or y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned."

Comment: What you may want is: `json.loads('' or '{}')` - returns an empty dict instead of `None`. But this depends on your case of course.

Answer (score 0):

To give another way that worked for me, I used the **inline if** which returns an empty string if there is no data to load:
As seen below I wanted to load the request form data which is the session id

```
session_id = json.loads(request.form['session_id']) if request.form['session_id'] else ''
```

Comment: This will still fail if `request.form['session_id']` is empty or None. As in else part you are again passing `''` which leads to exception @LiLika